# How can I display a JavaFX Browser in a Java JPanel application?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, netbeans, javafx-8

Good Community I am making an app and I am working with a java browser googlemap and I want to show it in a panel or in another element where it is displayed (`JLabel`, `JPanel`, etc).

I made a project in java-> javaAplication-> a form -> with a button. This is the method I am calling on the button.

```
locate ();
```

I want to display it in a `JPanel` not in an `FXPanel` like this now:

```
    private void locate() {
String a = txtMapaBuscador.getText().replace(" ", "+");


final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(1280, 720);
frame.setVisible(true);

final JFXPanel fxpanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.add(fxpanel);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebEngine engine;
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        engine = wv.getEngine();
        fxpanel.setScene(new Scene(wv));
        engine.load("https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + a);
    }
});
}
```

This is my friend's code but I can't understand it.

```
package simpleswingbrowser;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.FAILED;

public class SimpleSwingBrowser extends JFrame {

    private final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    private WebEngine engine;

    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private final JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel();

    private final JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
    private final JTextField txtURL = new JTextField();
    private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    public SimpleSwingBrowser() {
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        createScene();

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loadURL(txtURL.getText());
            }
        };

        btnGo.addActionListener(al);
        txtURL.addActionListener(al);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        topBar.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topBar.add(btnGo, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        statusBar.add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();

                engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                SimpleSwingBrowser.this.setTitle(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                lblStatus.setText(event.getData());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                txtURL.setText(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker()
                        .exceptionProperty()
                        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                            @Override
                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable old, final Throwable value) {
                                if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                            panel,
                                            (value != null)
                                            ? engine.getLocation() + "\n" + value.getMessage()
                                            : engine.getLocation() + "\nUnexpected error.",
                                            "Loading error...",
                                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });

                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String tmp = toURL(url);

                if (tmp == null) {
                    tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SimpleSwingBrowser browser = new SimpleSwingBrowser();
                browser.setVisible(true);
                browser.loadURL("http://oracle.com");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A `JFXPanel` is the only swing component capable of displaying JavaFX content. It's not clear what you want to do that's different to what you've already done.

Comment: I want to show it in a java swing jpanel

Comment: my friend could but I don't quite understand what he did

Comment: Just put the `JFXPanel` inside a `JPanel`.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, but how do I do it. I am trying various things but I get an error or it doesn't appear, help

Comment: but you posted a solution that does exactly that.

Comment: is that it is a solution that I don't understand and I don't know how to add it or dock it in my project because it doesn't work for me, that's why I need help

Comment: and if someone understands it, they would be nice to help me because I don't know how to place a jxpanel in a jpanel

Comment: and I think it would be cool for other people to see it since we can use any page in a jpanel

Comment: What don’t you understand? It creates a `JPanel` with `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());` and then puts the `JFXPanel` inside it with `panel.add(jfxPanel, ...);`

Comment: hey thank you very much I found my error thanks to you, it happens that I was not creating a panel I just added it to my frame and called it `pnlViewMapa.add (fxpanel);`. The error is that I was not putting `BorderLayout ()` you made me realize that part of the code. `pnlShowMap.add (fxpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` . THANK YOU CRACK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `JPanel pnlViewMap` in my frame and put `BorderLayout` and the map appeared

```
 pnlViewMapa.add(fxpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebEngine engine;
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        engine = wv.getEngine();
        fxpanel.setScene(new Scene(wv));
        engine.load("https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + a);
    }
});
```